# Arc Length with Vector-Valued Functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

"Consider the path of a particle in a conservative force field represented by the vector-valued function $r(t) = \langle 4(\sin t - t \cos t), 4(\sin t + t \sin t), (\frac{3}{2})t^2 \rangle$."

"A) Find the arc length function $s$."

"D) Show that $|r'(t)| = 1$."

To do this, I took the first derviative of the function. Then, I set up the square root of the sum of each dervived component squared. However, I could not get this to simplify down to $1$, as I assume I should be able to by the instructions in part D. My prof suggests reparameterizing the original function to make the problem simpler. Any thoughts on the new parameter?

Comment: Are you sure part D does not ask about $r^\prime (s)$?

Comment: $|r'(t)|$ cannot be $1$. The derivative of the z-component is $3t$, which is unbounded, so the magnitude can never be just $1$.

Comment: No, the questions says |r'(t)| = 1 .

Comment: Looks like a typo of some kind. Logically the new parameter would be $s$.

Comment: Ok, well assuming it is a typo, do you have any ideas for what s is equal to?

Comment: I believe you already have a function for $s(t)$. It's a complicated integral of a square root with a bunch of sines, cosines, and $t$ in it. I wouldn't try to use it for part (D). I'll give an answer for part (D).

Comment: Part B asks that you use the results from part A to find r(s). Could you explain that as well? I can post it as a new question, if you'd prefer so you can get points for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$s(t)=\int_0^t |\mathbf r'(\tau)|d\tau$$
Therefore:
$$s'(t)=|\mathbf r'(t)|$$

The chain rule and the inverse derivative rule tell us that:
$$\mathbf r'(s)=\frac{d\mathbf r}{ds} = \frac{d\mathbf r}{dt} \frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{\mathbf r'(t)}{s'(t)} $$

So that:
$$\mathbf r'(s)=\frac{\mathbf r'(t)}{|\mathbf r'(t)|} \Rightarrow |\mathbf r'(s)|=\frac{|\mathbf r'(t)|}{|\mathbf r'(t)|}=1$$