# About the Arc length of a 3D curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

How could I get to the answer to this problem?

Given the function: $r(t)=\langle t,3\cos t,3\sin t\rangle$

How can I find the the arc length between these points $(0,3,0)$ and $(\frac{\pi}{2},0,3)$?

Comment: There is a pretty straghtforward formula for the arc length. Do you have that? And you need to determine the values of $t$ corresponding to the two points.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/856695/620957

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Take the tangent $d {\bf r} / dt$, make it unitary ($\bf u$), then $d {\bf r}= {\bf u}ds$.